# grep regex pattern matches on each line where only all matches appear and print on same line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, regex, grep

trying to extract some patterns per line, from a log file.
I am trying to extract the first time stamp, and two or three other matches but I want to be able to only print the matches from the lines where all the matches appear.
Is there a single grep command that I can do this with, or do I have to loop through each line?

My log line is like this

`2018-08-07 08:55:20 ERROR[t-dispatcher-24]  - Error while processing message: code:[RequestTimeout], message:[{"from_addr_type": null, "transport_name": "999_abc_999_2_1", "in_reply_to": null, "group": null, "timestamp": "2018-08-07 07:55:19.795748", "from_addr": "341231231234", "message_type": "user_message", "helper_metadata": {}, "to_addr": "ABCD", "to_addr_type": null, "session_id": "157692", "content": "0013091779", "routing_metadata": {}, "message_version": "20110921", "transport_type": "XXXX", "provider": "abc_somewhere", "transport_metadata": {"abc_somewhere_XXXX": {"clientId": "XXXX157692", "starCode": "999", "session_id": "157692", "phase": "2", "dcs": "15", "requestId": "157692"}}, "session_event": "resume", "message_id": "5d9cab5353ff449783a737e8390a690b"}]`

I want to be able to extract certain groups like the timestamp at the start, the "content" and "to_addr" sections.

I came up with this:
`grep -oP '(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})|"to_addr":"\K(\d+)|"content":\K"(.+?)"' | tr -d '\n'`

But Im unable to select only the lines where all three pattern matches exist.
Please what am I doing wrong?
Am I expecting too much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an OR `|` between your patterns, you want an AND.

In your pattern, you're searching for `"to_addr":"\K(\d+)` but i your example the value of `to_addr` is `ABCD` so it doesn't match with `\d+` and there is a space between `"to_addr:` and  `"ABCD"`, same for `content`.

If `to_addr` is always before `content`:

```
grep -P '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*?"to_addr": "\d+.*?"content": ".+?"'
```

Else use lookaheads:

```
grep -P '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?=.*?"to_addr": "\d+)(?=.*?"content": "(.+?)")'
```

If you want to print only the matches, I suggest a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ane 'print "$1\t$2\t$3\n" if (/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(?=.*?"to_addr": "(\d+))(?=.*?"content": "(.+?)")/)' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This allows me to select the lines perfectly, but how can I print just the matches from each line, on the same line?

Comment: @Sina: I suggest using a perl one-liner, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks! Very beautiful one-liner! I did a small script:  `while  IFS=' ' read -r line; do value0=$(echo "$line" | grep -oP '^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'); value1=$(echo "$line" |grep -oP '"to_addr":"\K(\d+)'); value2=$(echo "$line" | grep -oP '"content":"\K(.+?")'); printf "%s %s %s\n" "$value0" "$value1" "$value2"; done <source_file >> output_file`
  but I am always grateful to get perl.